# Feynman Propagator in Position Space through Schwinger Parameter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, wick-rotation, propagator

So I am aware of a thread at [Propagator of a scalar in position space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/101886/) but it does not answer my question, which is more about poles in position space.

Starting from

$$D_F(x_1-x_2) = \int \frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{i}{k^2-m^2+i\epsilon}e^{i k\cdot x}$$

I have been able to show that

$$D_F(x_1-x_2) = \frac{-i}{16\pi^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ds}{s^2}\exp\left[-i\frac{X^2}{4s}\right]\exp\left[-i(m^2-i\epsilon)s\right]$$

which by change of variable can be written as

$$ D_F(x_1-x_2) = \frac{-i}{16\pi^2}[i(m^2-i\epsilon)]\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{t^2}\exp\left[-t-\frac{[-(m^2-i\epsilon)X^2]}{4t}\right].$$

Using the integral representation of $K_1(z)$ (the modified Bessel function of the second kind) I can see that

$$D_F(x_1-x_2) = \frac{(m^2-i\epsilon)}{16\pi^2}\frac{4}{\sqrt{-(m^2-i\epsilon)X^2}}K_1(\sqrt{-(m^2-i\epsilon)X^2}).$$

But I know that the **correct answer** is

$$D_F(x_1-x_2) = -\frac{i}{4\pi^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{-X^2 + i\epsilon}}K_1(im\sqrt{-X^2 + i\epsilon}).$$

What bothers me is how $\sqrt{-(m^2-i\epsilon)X^2}$ is equal to $\sqrt{im(-X^2 + i\epsilon)}$, because according to me

$$\sqrt{-(m^2-i\epsilon)X^2)} = \sqrt{-m^2(1-i\epsilon)X^2} = im\sqrt{X^2 - i\epsilon}$$

**What's the error here?**

Comment: So my confusion in the last step stems from the book 'Analytic Tools for Feynman Integrals' by Vladimir A. Smirnov (Springer 2012). The equation just above equation (2.17) gives the "correct answer" which has a manifestly different form.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I have [a similar one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/179010/the-poles-of-feynman-propagator-in-position-space)

Comment: My solution appears in my post.

Comment: I refer to the book you mentioned and get to the step before changing variable. Can you teach me how you change $s$ to $t$? Thanks!

Comment: I took $t = i X^24s$ from the looks of it...

Comment: Then the integration should be from $i*0$ to $i*\infty$ but not $0$ to $\infty$. Do I miss something?