# Massive Two-Point Function of Scalars in Position-Minkowski Space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, correlation-functions, propagator

What does the two-point position space function of **massive** scalars look like in Minkowski space?

$$\langle 0| \phi(x) \phi (y)|0\rangle =\ ?$$

I've been trying to better understand the analytic behavior of some simple correlators and realized I don't quite know how to write down such a function.  Is there a closed form which I can learn about its poles, cuts, etc.?

Usually when discussing such objects authors will just write this as a Fourier transform of momentum space, $D(x,y)=\langle 0| \phi(x) \phi (y)|0\rangle =\int e^{-i p(x-y)} D(p)$, without actually evaluating the Fourier transform.  I'm worried I am missing some subtleties when I try to do it myself.  Other authors will argue that if we think about the physics, we should really be concerned with causal objects and so we should consider a related object like $\langle0| [\phi(x), \phi (y)]|0\rangle $. (For example Peskin & Schroeder pp. 27-29)

This seems like a basic object so I am assuming I have some very basic misunderstanding.  The only time I ever see such an object discussed in physics is when dealing with a CFT.  Here, however, one is always interested in a massless theory (we don't need no scales!).

Edits:

1. One suggestion is just to use [this procedure](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101886/propagator-of-a-scalar-in-position-space), but I believe the starting point there involves a *time-ordered* correlation function (i.e. Feynman propagator).  I'm specifically interested in the *non-time-ordered* case.
2. Another suggestion is that I should be careful about my language.  This seems the providence of Wightman functions and more general distributions in field theory, but alas this is not my forte.

Comment: Although that is known as the 2 point _function_, it doesn't mean that it is a "function" in the proper sense. This is unfortunate terminology, as Wightman functions are tempered distributions in each of the "variables".

Comment: I had an inkling I should have been using the language of more generalized distributions, Wightman functions, but wasn't sure I was on the right track.

Comment: AccidentalFourierTransform: I had already been through that post and unfortunately I don't think it answers my question.  There they show that one can take the position space Feynman propagator, take the massless limit, and they recover the result for a massless propagator.  The starting point, Feynman Propagator, is defined for a time-ordered product.  I'm specifically interested in the correlator without time ordering.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform No problem!  Indeed, I ended up reading through a whole boat load of similar responses like that thinking "gah my question must have been asked before!"

Comment: It is done in Eqn(71) in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9908140
Given in terms of BesselK.
May be I should post this as a comment. I haven't check it. Hope this hope helps.

Answer (score 2):

These sorts of expressions are discussed in older quantum field theory books, such as Bjorken & Drell and Bogoliubov & Shirkov. In *Quantum Fields*, by Bogoliubov & Shirkov, the expression for the two-point function of a massive scalar field in Minkowski spacetime can be read from the expressions given on Appendix V.2. Specifically, one has (up to typos as I copy down the expression)
$$\langle 0 | \phi(x) \phi(0) |0 \rangle = \frac{\mathrm{sign}(x^0) \delta(\lambda)}{4\pi i} - \frac{m \Theta(\lambda)}{8 \pi i \sqrt{\lambda}}\left[\mathrm{sign}(x^0) J_1(m \sqrt{\lambda}) - i N_1(m \sqrt{\lambda}) \right] + \frac{m \Theta(-\lambda)}{4 \pi^2 \sqrt{-\lambda}} K_1(m \sqrt{-\lambda}),$$
where $\lambda = (x^0)^2 - ||\vec{x}||^2$, $J_1$, $Y_1$, and $K_1$ are the Bessel functions, $\Theta$ is Heaviside's theta function, and $\mathrm{sign}$ is the sign function.

There are some discussions about this and other related propagators on [n-Lab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hadamard+distribution#ForKleinGordonOperatorOnMinkowskiSpacetime). n-Lab also lists [this table](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/KGPropagatorsOnMinkowskiTable.pdf) on commutator functions and propagators that might be useful to understand the pole structures and so on.